# Get column index and current value from datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to get current column index and current value from this foreach loop? Please, I need to finish my school task.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tradeGridView.Rows)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code iterate all the datagrid rows, if you want to retrive the selected columns tradeGridView.SelectedColumns();
You can try this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tradeGridView.Rows)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < tradeGridView.SelectedColumns.Count; i++)
        {
            //INDEX
            var index = tradeGridView.SelectedColumns[i].Index;
            //VALUE
            var value = row[index]
        }
}
```

if you want only the selected row change tradeGridView.Rows with tradeGridView.SelectedRows